# Recover formatted drive

Tags: windows, formatting, file-recovery

Here is my question,

I have formated my C drive and installed windows on it, but I lost some important file I have used many recovery tools but it is not showing that folder itself

I am using XAMPP for PHP programming all the files inside c:/xampp folder.

any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Well the only solutions is to get it from your backup. If you have no backup i feel really sorry about your lost work.

Windows is notorious in rearranging and playing with files on it's own accord.

Try to use photorec it might help but i highly doubt it at this phase.

Comment: "Windows is notorious in rearranging and playing with files on it's own accord." - What does that mean exactly and can you provide examples or documentation to illustrate your point?

Comment: simply it tries to be smart and move your files to different hdd sectors so they can be accessed faster, but this performs terrible in most cases. This is the main reason why disks get fragmented and need to be defragmented. This is the reason it is recommended not to use the prefetch help. This is the reason why most people disable background disk optimizations (at least i don't know of anyone that leaves it enabled).

Answer (score 1):

Windows keeps a table that tells it where on your disk files are kept. When you delete a file Windows throws away the reference, but the data is still on disk, but is now eligilble to be written over. A quick format behaves similarly. The longer you continue to use a drive the more likely parts of files will be written over. Your problem is compounded by the re-install of Windows that may have already destroyed your data.

Should you format a drive and want to recover data, your best bet is to power it down as soon as possible and mount it in a second machine as a non-boot drive and then run recovery software on it. Alternatively you could boot using a live cd and try to recover your files that way.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid as Zeridon said you are at a loss without backups. Sadly formatting does exactly what it says on the tin. It might be a good lesson in good backup practice to avoid the same problem in the future.